# HttpClient is caching requests to the same URL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

On Xamarin iOS. I'm using HttpClient to get a JSON string. The problem is that it ignores updates and gives me the same JSON response if I query the same URL. I want it to not cache anything and always actually query the URL and give me the new response.

This sounds trivial, there must be a simple way for this. I'm using a Forms shared project.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are setting the cache-control header to no-cache?
`client.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl.NoCache = true;`

If so but it still doesn't work - maybe the server is caching the response? If it comes down to it, you can usually defeat something like that by adding a cachebuster to the querystring though. Just append a bogus param and pass it a unique value each time. For example, if your URL is `http://my.url.com/resource/someid` then you can defeat the caching by using `http://my.url.com/resource/someid?b=1` and then increment that "b" param with each call.

Comment: Haven't tried that, I'll try it tonight once I'm back. The server isn't caching. I read about the URL truck before, but it doesn't solve the core problem.

Comment: Any luck solving the issue? For now I append a timestamp to each sent request (not nice)